# SQL SERVER (2008) debug IF condition

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Is there a way to debug sql servers if condition rules in sql servers?

Best would be if there is an answer for sql 2008, but if thats possbile only in later versions, then please tell me, since i cant find this by asking @Google

**For example:**

```
    DECLARE @note4 nvarchar(max)
    select @note4 = note4 from inserted

    DECLARE @profileid int
    select @profileid = profileid from inserted


    IF (@note4 <> '' and @note4 is not null and @profileid in (123,1234))
    BEGIN
        --some code goes here
    END
```

So is there a way to see what return these conditions, when i am doing debug?

```
@note4 <> ''
@note4 is not null
@profileid in (123,1234)
```

are they FALSE or TRUE?

Comment: You can just select the conditions?

Comment: Tried to add to watch, just condition 
`'IF (@note4 <> '' and @note4 is not null and @profileid in (123))' could not be evaluated`

And if i selected just part of this, same result `'@note4 <> ''' could not be evaluated 
`

Comment: I'm unsure where you're going here, but depending on `--some code goes here` you would be much better off to simply do JOIN based logic instead of IF based logic (after all SQL is build upon set-based logic, so might as well use it). It will make it a lot easier to test by running the query against test data.

Comment: @AllanS.Hansen Well, i am more intrested in being able to see, which conditions is returning true and which is returning false. (Not just in this case but in general)
Since i have no problems now, but there might be so after time, so i want make sure i know how to debug this code.
And i am sorry, but i cant change code.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to see what each one returns, you could do before your main if:

```
IF (@note4 <> '') 
BEGIN 
PRINT 'true @note4 <> '''''
END
IF (@note4 is not null) 
BEGIN 
PRINT 'true @note4 is not null'
END
IF (@profileid in (123,1234)) 
BEGIN 
PRINT 'true @profileid in (123,1234)'
END
```

Comment: Well, i am asking about debugging. Ofcourse u can add lines like this, but when i debug, i would like to know if i can see, what returns if conditions.
In this provided code, u can easily modify to see, but what if code is much longer? i dont want to add all time all IF by hand, thats gross.